# how to pass information gotten from a html page to the server through local area network (Ethernet cable )

Tags: php, html, lan

I have an form handler  were all my users informations will be passed to on my server,  I have an html form where the users are required to type in their names, select their gender by clicking on a radio button, type in their email address and other of their informations and then click the "Submit" button

But the computer they will be using Is not connected online, it is a local area network "LAN" connection, I have 15 computers connected to the network and a laptop as a server.

Now I want the informations gotten from the users to be passed to the form handler  on the local area network once the submit button is clicked, but I don't know how to go about it please help me

This is the form code but I am unable to type in all the code because I am uploading this question from my Android phone and typing all the code is a hell of work

```
<form action="/action_page.php">
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname"
value="Mickey"><br>
Last name:<br>
<input type="text" name="lastname"
value="Mouse"><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: presumably the `"Server"` can be contacted by each computer on the LAN and presumably each computer can access the webserver on the `"server"`? If yes -set the form action to the form handler on the `"server"`

Answer (score 0):

1. Find the LAN ip address of the laptop (server) - ipconfig/all for windows (cmd); ifconfig Linux/Mac (terminal)
2. Host the server using Apache/php or any other server of your choice.
3. Load the webpage using the LAN ip of the laptop with the appropriate port number.

Answer (score -1):

I'm assuming that you already have a LAMP or WAMP environment running in the Laptop (Server).

So if you want to send the form info to the server from a local machine (I mean that you have .html file as local file in a computer) you have to add the hostname or IP address to the form action parameter.

If you have the .html file served if your LAMP/WAMP environment just check that the "/action_page.php" file is served in the root of your project

Answer (score -1):

Set the form action to the `action_page.php` script on the webserver / laptop

```
<form method='post' action='http://server.corporate.lan/action_page.php'>
    First name:<br><input type='text' name='firstname' value='Mickey'><br>
    Last name:<br><input type='text' name='lastname'value='Mouse'><br><br>
    <input type='submit' />
</form>
```